# Openni log file location and how to enable it

Tags: kinect, openni, openni2, xtion, primesense

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

1. Could anyone tell me where is the Log folder when running Niviewer or Niviewer2? I install openni 1.5.4 and openni2 through ros package through apt-get as a dependence of ros-hydro-openni-camera and ros-hydro-openni2-camera. I installed Niviewer and Niviewer2 through openni-utils in apt-get. I assume I will get the same Log folder location when I run through ros-hydro-openni-launch and please correct me if I'm wrong.
2. I also want to make sure the right way to enable the log file is to modify the line in /etc/openni/GlobalDefaults.ini (Openni) or in /etc/openni2/OpenNi.ini
   from

   `;LogWriteToFile=1`

   to

   `LogWriteToFile=1`
3. Do I have to restart the computer for the modification to take effect or is there anyway for it to take effect without restarting the computer?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/186437/openni-log-file-location-and-how-to-enable-it/) by [Fei Liu](https://answers.ros.org/users/720/fei-liu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2014-07-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2014-07-14**:
Did you look in `~/.ros`?

**Comment by [Fei Liu](https://answers.ros.org/users/720/fei-liu/) on 2014-07-14**:
I looked at ~/.ros, didn't find any clue. ~/.ros contains only ros related log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've found that the openni driver doesn't seem to honor the openni log settings, but the openni samples do, and they're sufficient for debugging device and driver issues.

Try making those changes and then running one of the samples:

```
Sample-NiSimpleRead
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-11-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0